# Understanding function type signatures

Tags: syntax, ocaml, type-inference, higher-order-functions, type-signature

I'm having trouble understanding function type signatures for higher-order functions in OCaml.

```
fun f -> f 3
(int -> a) -> a
```

The way I process this is that `f 3` part takes an `int` as input and returns the type defined by the function `f` which is denoted as `a`. So really, `fun f` is a type `(int->a)`. But then where is the last **`a`** coming from in `(int -> a) ->` **`a`**?

Answer (score 5):

Your first example is this:

```
fun f -> f 3
```

I think that one possible confusion you might be having is that you're thinking of this as the definition of a function named `f`. This is not the case. This is an anonymous value representing a function, also known as a lambda. The `f` represents the *paramter* of this anonymous function.

To keep things clearer, let's give the function the name `g`. In other words, assume that we define `g` like this:

```
let g = fun f -> f 3
```

OK, so `g` is a function that takes one parameter `f`. This `f` parameter is obvously a function since we see it being applied to 3. (I.e., we see it being called with 3 as the argument.) What does `g` return? It returns whatever `f` returns when you call it, right?

Since `g` is a function its type must be something of this form:

```
d -> c
```

I.e., it accepts something of type `d` and returns something of type `c`. From the reasoning above, we know that `d` is a function type, and we also know that the return type of this function is also the return type of `g`. So if `d` is (in more detail) `b -> a`, then the full type of `g` is like this:

```
(b -> a) -> a
```

However we also know that the function parameter `f` takes an int argument because we see it being applied to 3. So the type `b` must be `int`. This gives us the following for the type of `g`:

```
(int -> a) -> a
```

I hope this helps make things clearer.

Comment: ... IOW, just to drive the point home, `fun` does not belong to just `f`, but to the whole expression `(fun f -> f 3)` -- an anonymous, "lambda" function. In Scheme, for example, it would be written as `(lambda (f) (f 3))`.

Comment: What might help as well is to write `let g = fun f -> f 3` as `let g f = f 3`... in mathematics, a named function might be written as `h(x) = x + 3` and in lambda notation, this is `h = fun x -> x + 3`.

Answer (score 0):

We could annotate the anonymous function thus:

```ml
fun (f : int -> 'a) -> (f 3 : 'a)
```

I.e., it's a function from `f : int -> 'a` to `'a`, so this is where your last `'a` is coming from.